# Specify command line arguments for Python modules in distributed way (like abseil does)

Tags: python, coding-style, command-line-arguments, argparse, abseil

How can I specify command line arguments on a per module base, that are then parsed when the application is run. This is basically how [ABSEIL](https://abseil.io/docs/python/guides/flags) flags work, but I would prefer a more lightweight solution. Can this be achieved with argparse or any other python library? 
Example:

```
# trainer.py
specify_argument('learning_rate', float)
...
```

```
# model.py
specify_argument('num_layers', int)
...
```

```
# main.py
def main(): 
  parse_args()
  ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would just use abseil if you want that feature.

I don't know any other library doing this.

You could hand craft something, but I seriously think it's not worth the effort if abseil can do what you want.